# Deleting users registry with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I recently started working at a school and we are doing our bi-yearly wiping of user accounts from all of the computers. We use persistent accounts for all of the students to reduce wear on the HDDs, reduce network load, and to reduce boot time. For deleting the user folders we use this script:

```
@echo off
cd \.
cd \Users\
dir *20**
echo Users to be deleted
pause
@echo on
for /D %%f in (*20**) do rmdir %%f /s /q
pause
exit
```

The only issue is when multiple grades use the same computer a student that had their profile downloaded to the computer the previous year isn't able to login as their registry is still present on the computer.  How would I go about removing their registry entries (with batch if possible) that way there wouldn't be any registry conflicts?

All of our computers are running Windows 10 if that changes anything. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete Registry entry of a certain student on a remote PC, save this script to *test.bat*, and run it from open **Admin Cmd Prompt**. Replace *PC_name* and *user* values with your own. You can use wildcards in the user name, i.e. `"user=.*20.*"` to delete Reg data of all users with name like *AshleyPalm-2016*. It works well for me. Let me know if any errors pop up:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "PC_name=remote_PC_name" & set "user=.*20.*" & echo/
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%H in (`reg query \\%PC_name%\HKEY_USERS`) do (
    set "val=\\%PC_name%\%%H\Volatile Environment"
    for /f "usebackq tokens=3 skip=1" %%K in (`reg query "!val!" /v USERNAME 2^>nul`) do (
        echo %%K | findstr /r /e /c:"%user%" >nul && (echo Deleting %%K: %%H & reg delete \\%PC_name%\%%H )))
exit /b
```

Read more here: [Reg command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb490984.aspx) (MS), [FINDSTR](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Comment: If the script works for you and you'll need more help in the future, pls  consider **Upvoting** and **Accepting** the answer by clicking both _Arrow Up_ and _Select_ signs to the left of the _Answer Box_. Some novices to this portal don't know about these helpful features. :)

Comment: Is there anyway to use wildcards for this? In my batch script we name every user with their graduation year ie. 2016 and use `*20**` as our wild card for any user with 20 and 2 digits afterwards to delete all of the student folders in C:\Users. Is there a way to do that but to the registries?

Comment: Updated the script. Read the Answer and follow instructions carefully. Read also the 1st note above. :)

Comment: I ran the script and it didn't give any output. I ran it from Admin Cmd Prompt. I also put the name of the pc in as well.  Didn't delete anything either. There are 20+ users in the registry. I have upvoted but it won't show until I have 15 reputation. I will mark your answer as the selected answer once it gets figured out. Thank you for the tips. :)

Comment: Running it remotely gives me "ERROR: the network path was not found"

Comment: Alright. In the code you're using HKEY_USERS. The users folders have already been deleted and the users aren't in that directory. I need to remove the registry values in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList Which gives me an invalid syntax error. @sambul35

Comment: Remote registration service wasn't started. I wound up just using Delprof2GUI and it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing experience about this kind of stuff: I'm kind of administating a pool of Windows XP machines, with domain accounts but local profiles.

We started with roaming profiles, but it was so hectic that we decided to switch to local profiles by default (by changing some system registry key). There was the question of destroying corrupt roaming user profiles so they will be created as local profiles afterwards.

In that case, removing everything in `%USERPROFILE%` for a given user removes the file `NTUSER.DAT` and thus all his/her settings/registry entries (but not the right to connect again)

After that, if the student connects with a non-existing profile, Windows creates a standard profile cloned from `Default User` profile.

This does not work if the machine has not been rebooted after user successful login: `NTUSER.DAT` subsists, but not the other files, which may be problematic, and maybe the problem that you're having.

What I'd do:

- remote reboot of all machines to unlock `NTUSER.DAT` files
- for all machines, remotely destroy the `Users` sub-dirs (you just need an extra `for` loop containing all your machines and access the drives like that: `\\host\C$\Users` (provided that `Users` is on C drive)

Comment: We have about 100 machines to do this to and from what my boss said unfortunately this wont work on windows 7 and above.